# Query SQL data in Flask to use for charting without using the app.route decorator

Tags: python, sql-server, d3.js, flask

I am trying to query a SQL server in Flask, so that I can plot the data using d3.js.

The way I've seen some people doing it (e.g. [here](http://www.datasciencebytes.com/bytes/2015/02/28/using-flask-to-answer-sql-queries/)) seems to be like this

1. Create a function that retrieves the data
2. Use the `@app.route(/get_data)` decorator
3. Use the URL in d3.js and create a chart

Is there any way to skip the "data publishing step"? That is, not publishing the bare data at `/get_data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have some manner of getting the request from the client to the server and the response from the server back to the client. Setting up a route is a quick and easy way of doing it. Another option is websockets, but that can involve a fair bit more of setup to get running properly. You wouldn't have to have a separate endpoint just for the data, though.

To start, take a look at [Flask-SocketIO](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO). The [documentation](http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent) are excellent resources.

The minimal app presented in the tutorial is

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('my event', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    emit('my response', {'data': message['data']})

@socketio.on('my broadcast event', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    emit('my response', {'data': message['data']}, broadcast=True)

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected'})

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/test')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

You'll have to setup both the front and back ends of the connection, and send a command from the client:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
    socket.on('my response', function(msg) {
        $('#log').append('<p>Received: ' + msg.data + '</p>');
    });
    socket.emit('my event');
});
```

receive and process with the backend, and return a response.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Definitely a lot harder with respect to the conventional way. Thanks for taking the time to explain the whole process! Very much appreciated.